# How to play live MPEG-DASH stream in chromecast's default receiver?

Tags: live-streaming, chromecast

I'm trying to make a live stream play on chromecast, but it fails. Though I can play other MPEG-DASH videos (i.e. http://dash.edgesuite.net/dash264/TestCases/1a/netflix/exMPD_BIP_TC1.mpd)

I'm using https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-chrome as basis for my sender app.

Weird thing is that when I load the media file, it seems to load it:

```
new media session ID:1
```

Though the player state switches from PAUSED to IDLE very quickly. And IDLE reason is error.

Is there a way to see the real error message?

Can a live stream be played on default receiver?

If so, is there anything special I need take care of in the sender app?

Comment: Contents of mine MPD file - http://pastebin.com/33Jhsa5B

Comment: Turn on debugging on the receiver and see what shows up there in the log

Comment: Is it possible to debug default receiver? Is there a guide how to do it?

Comment: Yes, read about it here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver, section "Debugging"

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar behaviour with the [Cast Media Player Streaming Demo](https://github.com/googlecast/CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM). I found a DASH live stream [here](http://www.dash-player.com/demo/live-streaming/), which seams to be available 24/7 - trying it on ChromeCast the player state is IDLE and no error is shown, although the video is not playing.

The HLS live case works for me, so I am wondering if ChromeCast is capable of playing DASH live streams, and if so I would be interested in a sample MPD. Does anyone know?

Comment: The sample that you used already has a reference to an mpeg-dash content. Doesn't that work?

Comment: The DASH samples work fine, also other non-live streams do not show any issues. However, there is no live DASH stream listed, I tried different live streams from other sources, but non of them was working.

Comment: I suggest you use a Styled Receiver and collect the logs from chromecast's console and open an issue on our issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list)